# Solving 2D Coupled Nonlinear SO Coupled Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, physics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve coupled nonlinear SO coupled equations in 2D from the following two papers https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.08849.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.00491.pdf. They have given an input seed as a sinusoidal wave multiplied by a small gaussian wave. The coupled Equations and their energy expression are as follows

[image]

Here is my code

```
boundary = 20; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary; finalt = 2;
\[Eta]value = 1; \[Gamma]value = 0.5; V = 0; c0value = -0.5; c2value \
= -0.5;
  firstseed[x_, y_] := 
 Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/32] (Cos[\[Gamma]value x] + Cos[\[Gamma]value y]); 
secondseed[x_, y_] := 
 Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/32] (-Sin[\[Gamma]value x] - 
    I \[Eta]value Sin[\[Gamma]value y]);

sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      V*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Psi][x, y, t] + 
      c0value Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] + 
      c2value Abs[\[Phi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, 
        t] + \[Gamma]value (-I \[Eta]value D[\[Phi][x, y, t], y] + 
         D[\[Phi][x, y, t], x]),
    
     -D[\[Phi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      V*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Phi][x, y, t] + 
      c0value Abs[\[Phi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Phi][x, y, t] + 
      c2value Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Phi][x, y, 
        t] - \[Gamma]value (I \[Eta]value D[\[Psi][x, y, t], y] + 
         D[\[Psi][x, y, t], x]),
    
    \[Psi][xl, y, t] == firstseed[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
     firstseed[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
     firstseed[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 
     firstseed[x, yr], \[Psi][x, y, 0] == firstseed[x, y],
    
    \[Phi][xl, y, t] == secondseed[xl, y], \[Phi][xr, y, t] == 
     secondseed[xr, y], \[Phi][x, yl, t] == 
     secondseed[x, yl], \[Phi][x, yr, t] == 
     secondseed[x, yr], \[Phi][x, y, 0] == secondseed[x, y]},
   {\[Psi][x, y, t], \[Phi][x, y, t]}, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 
    0, finalt},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 81, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}},
    MaxSteps -> 10^6];

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[\[Psi][x, y, finalt]]^2 /. sol], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, 
  yr}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 350, 
 LabelStyle -> {24, Bold, Large, Black}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["y", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
    None}, {Style["x", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     FontSlant -> "Italic", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 30], 
    None}}]
```

Comment: What about your question?

Comment: I am trying to find \psi^2 and \phi^2 and energy @AlexTrounev if possible similar to fig.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.08849.pdf

Comment: The nearly same thing is done in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.00491.pdf  like fig 3 or 4. I could not find your email id at https://www.docsie.io/.

Comment: The FORTRAN version can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.13507.pdf.

Comment: Please submit your resume to admin@likalo.com with words to Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't solve this system with imaginary time method at negative `c0value = -0.5; c2value = -0.5;`. But we can solve it at positive `c0value = 1; c2value = 50;` as in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.00491.pdf) as follows

```
boundary = 4 Pi; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = 
 yr = boundary; finalt = 2; rho = 1; om = 1/2;
\[Eta]value = 1; \[Gamma]value = 12/10; V = 
 1/2; c0value = 1; c2value = 50;
firstseed[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/10]/Sqrt[rho] ;
secondseed[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/10] /Sqrt[rho];


{P, F} = 
  NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      V*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Psi][x, y, t] + 
      c0value Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, t] + 
      c2value Abs[\[Phi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Psi][x, y, 
        t] - \[Gamma]value ( 
        D[\[Phi][x, y, t], y] + I D[\[Phi][x, y, t], x] - 
         om \[Phi][x, y, t]), -D[\[Phi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      V*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Phi][x, y, t] + 
      c0value Abs[\[Phi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Phi][x, y, t] + 
      c2value Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 \[Phi][x, y, 
        t] - \[Gamma]value (- D[\[Psi][x, y, t], y] + 
         I D[\[Psi][x, y, t], x] - om \[Psi][x, y, t]), \[Psi][xl, y, 
      t] == firstseed[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
     firstseed[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
     firstseed[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 
     firstseed[x, yr], \[Psi][x, y, 0] == 
     firstseed[x, y], \[Phi][xl, y, t] == 
     secondseed[xl, y], \[Phi][xr, y, t] == 
     secondseed[xr, y], \[Phi][x, yl, t] == 
     secondseed[x, yl], \[Phi][x, yr, t] == 
     secondseed[x, yr], \[Phi][x, y, 0] == 
     secondseed[x, y]}, {\[Psi], \[Phi]}, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, 
    yr}, {t, 0, finalt}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 161, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

Visualization

```
DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[P[x, y, t]]^2 /. t -> finalt], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
  Pi}, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]

DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs[F[x, y, t]]^2 /. t -> finalt], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
  Pi}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTrounev. Do you think multiplication of Sin or Cos with gaussian function will lead to strips as mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.08849.pdf. As mentioned in the paper at the end of page 6 "To obtain these solitons the
stripe pattern is imprinted on the initial wave function as gaussian*Sin or Cos."

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Run code above with `\[Gamma]value = 5`, plot very nice picture with `DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[(Abs[P[x, y, t]]^2 + Abs[F[x, y, t]]^2) /. t -> finalt], {x,
   xl/2, xr/2}, {y, yl/2, yr/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`. This is striped like, unstable solution.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTrounev for your insightful solution. It was beneficial.